# difference: "hear of" vs. "hear about"

Tags: difference

I'm considering the difference between "hear of" and "hear about."

Is it possible to hear of a name without hearing about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference in nuance. And there are some differences in usage.

"Have you heard about dear Blanche?":
The speaker knows you know Blanche and wants to find out whether you heard about what happened to her (she got run down by an avalanche, as it happens!)

With "Have you heard of Bela Legosi?" you probably don't want to know much more than whether the listener recognises the name.

Very roughly, if you're talking about more or less detailed knowledge, you say "heard about" and if you want to know about simple recognition, you'll tend to say "heard of".

"I've heard of Ludwig Wittgenstein, but I don't think I've heard much about him."

If you're asking or reporting about news, you'll almost always use "heard about"?

"Have you hears about Dublin Bus? The drivers have gone on strike."

It's similar with "read of/about", for example.

But not with "speak/talk of/about" which, as far as I can tell, are pretty close synonyms, whose main difference is one of register (with 'of' being more formal than 'about').

"I spoke of her in a previous lecture" doesn't simply mean that I just mentioned her name, but rather more or less the same thing as "I spoke about her ..."

Comment: One case where "hear of" and "hear about" are more or less the same is "That's the last I heard of/about him." Do you agree?

Comment: Yep. I'd say you're right.